# Use ALAssetRepresentation getBytes:fromOffset:length:error: but with correct orientation

Tags: ios, objective-c, alassetslibrary

High level here is what I am trying to do in my iOS app:

1. Allow the user to select an asset from their Photo Library
2. Share a URL which entities external to my app can use to request that same asset
3. My app is running a webserver (CocoaHTTPServer) and it is able to serve up that data to the requesting entity
4. I intentionally implemented this using ALAssetRepresentation getBytes:fromOffset:length:error: , thinking that I could avoid the following headaches:

   - writing a local copy of the image before serving it up (and then having to manage the local copies)
   - putting all of the image data into memory
   - potentially slow performance, waiting to have the whole image before serving any of it

It works high level, with one problem.  The orientation of the image is not right in some cases.

This is a well known issue but the solutions generally seem to require creating a CGImage or UIImage from the ALAssetRepresentation.  As soon as I do that, it eliminates my ability to use that handy ALAssetRepresentation getBytes:fromOffset:length:error: method.

It would be cool if there is a way to continue to use this method but with the corrected orientation.  If not, I would appreciate any recommendations on a next best approach.  Thanks!

Here are a couple of relevant methods:

```
- (id)initWithAssetURL:(NSURL *)assetURL forConnection:(MyHTTPConnection *)parent{
if((self = [super init]))
{
    HTTPLogTrace();

    // Need this now so we can use it throughout the class
    self.connection = parent;
    self.assetURL = assetURL;

    offset = 0;

    // Grab a pointer to the ALAssetsLibrary which we can persistently use
    self.lib = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];

    // Really need to know the size of the asset, but we will also set a property for the ALAssetRepresentation to use later
    // Otherwise we would have to asynchronously look up the asset again by assetForURL
    [self.lib assetForURL:assetURL
         resultBlock:^(ALAsset *asset) {
             self.assetRepresentation = [asset defaultRepresentation];
             self.assetSize = [self.assetRepresentation size];
             // Even though we don't really have any data, this will enable the response headers to be sent
             // It will call our delayResponseHeaders method, which will now return NO, since we've set self.repr
             [self.connection responseHasAvailableData:self];
         }
        failureBlock:^(NSError *error) {
            // recover from error, then
            NSLog(@"error in the failureBlock: %@",[error localizedDescription]);
        }];
}
return self;
}

- (NSData *)readDataOfLength:(NSUInteger)lengthParameter{
HTTPLogTrace2(@"%@[%p]: readDataOfLength:%lu", THIS_FILE, self, (unsigned long)lengthParameter);

NSUInteger remaining = self.assetSize - offset;
NSUInteger length = lengthParameter < remaining ? lengthParameter : remaining;

Byte *buffer = (Byte *)malloc(length);
NSError *error;

NSUInteger buffered = [self.assetRepresentation getBytes:buffer fromOffset:offset length:length error:&error];
NSLog(@"Error: %@",[error localizedDescription]);
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy:buffer length:buffered freeWhenDone:YES];

// now that we've read data of length, update the offset for the next invocation
offset += length;

return data;
}
```